# How to dynamically remove input field which is created dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created an input text dynamically using JS, but what if I want to remove the input field one by one dynamically using a button by calling "`removeTextField()`" from the JS?

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTextField(){
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("name", "i[]");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("class", "daters");
    element.setAttribute("id", "timepicker_7");

    var myvalue = document.getElementById("dispTime");
    myvalue.appendChild(element);
}
</script>
```

...

```
<input type = "button" class="button2" value = "Add Time" onclick = "addTextField()"/>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Obviously you know how to create a function...

Comment: Why tag the question as `jQuery`, when it is not used at all?

Comment: And FYI, IDs must be unique, you should not call `addTextField()` more than one without removing #timepicker_7 element

Comment: jQuery, sorry, my mistake. Of course I can create a function. How can I dynamically remove an input field? - that is the question!

Answer (score 2):

1. The way you create the elements has a problem. You are giving the new element a hardcoded `id` and this means that when adding more than one, you will end with multiple elements with the same `id` ?(*which is invalid and prone to errors when accessing the DOM*)
2. Since you use jQuery, why not simplify your code when adding/removing elements by utilizing it?

I would use something like this

**html**

```
<input type="button" class="button2 addField" value="Add Time" />
<input type="button" class="button2 removeField" value="Remove Time" />
```

**script**

```
$(function(){
    $('.addField').on('click', function(){
        $('<input type="text">', {
              name: 'i[]',
              value: '',
              'class': 'daters'
        }).appendTo('#dispTime');
    });

    $('.removeField').on('click', function(){
         $('#dispTime .daters').last().remove();
    }); 
});
```

---

If you are not using jQuery then the way to remove an element

```
function removeTextField(){
   var elements = document.getElementById('dispTime').getElementByClassName('i[]'),
       last = elements[elements.length-1];

   last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use $.remove() for this..

refer: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Suggestion: instead of creating elements like the one you did, create like this.

```
  $('body').append("<input name='i[]' value='' class='daters' id='timepicker_7' />");

  $('#timepicker_7').remove();
```

if you are creating elements on demand and want to use this element multiple times.
now you have a function which can be used as many times you want, anywhere on the page

```
function GetTextField() {
    var field = "<input name='i[]' value='' class='daters' id='timepicker_7' />";
    return field;
}

var field = GetTextField();
$('body').append(field);
```

Comment: You are missing `#` before `timepicker_7`.

Comment: Also I wouldn't start function name with a capital, unless it's a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeTextField() {
    var timepicker = document.getElementByID("timepicker_7");
    timepicker.parentElement.removeChild(timepicker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dispTime #timepicker_7").remove()
```

Comment: Should I have to use this below `addTextField()` function?

Comment: you can directly add this on onclick event on delete button

Comment: Using two ids in a selector is excessive.

Comment: Two ids are only to specify hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea(not tested):

Every time you add an input, just push it in a array, so you can remove it after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputStack = new Array();
function addTextField(){
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("name", "i[]");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("class", "daters");
    element.setAttribute("id", "timepicker_7");

    var myvalue = document.getElementById("dispTime");
    myvalue.appendChild(element);
    inputStack.push(element);
}
// Now if you want to remove, just do this

inputStack[0].remove(); // I think it'll work for example
</script>
```